# Geometric distibution with parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm given the following question:

> Suppose that a quality control engineer wishes to test the durability of a child’s toy, the Widgetron. In order to do so, she repeatedly drops the Widgetrons from a height of one metre until the toy breaks on impact. The number of drops until breakage, call it $y$, is recorded. We will assume that the probability that the toy will not break stays constant from drop to drop, and this probability is independent of the number of times it has been dropped. If we define the random variable, $Y$, to represent the number of drops until the toy breaks, an appropriate probability model for the random variable $Y$ would be a Geometric model with parameter $\theta$.
>
> **How is $\theta$ interpreted in the context of this model?**

I don't know how to treat this question because the geometric distribution does not have any parameters besides the parameter $Y$. Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to treat this question because the geometric distribution does not have any parameters besides the parameter $Y$. Could someone please clarify?

No, $Y$, the count for drops until breakage, is the *random variable*.   It is not a parameter.

If $\theta$ is the parameter for this (one-shifted) Geometric Distribution, we would write $Y\sim\mathcal {Geo}_1(\theta)$.

$$\mathsf P(Y=k)~=~ (1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta~\mathbf 1_{k\in\{1,2,\ldots\}}$$

So, what does this parameter represent in this particular situation?

Comment: Thanks. [I've been able to solve this actually (should have removed the question)]. Then $\theta$ is the probability that a toy will break on the first drop, I think.

Comment: More that $\theta$ is the probability that the toy will break on any single drop.  The rate of breakage.

Comment: You're right, since the drops are independent of each other.